# Creating class diagram without code first?

Tags: java, eclipse, objectaid

I am using objectAid eclipse plugin to create class diagram. Say i have altready a customer class in my code.I can drag and drop.
But now i want to add address class in diagram . I don't have code ready for address class. How can i add address class in diagram
without address class ready in code? I do not see any control to add new box in object ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently ObjectAid only visualizes existing code. So you would have to create your Address class or interface (maybe in a branch) in order to show it in a diagram.